# Removal of outer square brackets from a response in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When i run my code it gives me extra square brackets in Response, and i want to get response without these SQUARE Brackets.

**Respose which i am getting is below.**
{"error":false,"message":"Login successfull","user":[{"u_id":"102","cust_name":"new","u_name":"user","cnic":"421","address":"sadaddd","cell_num":"43243","email":"n@gmail.com"}]}

**Response which i want must be that:** {"error":false,"message":"Login successfull","user":{"u_id":102,"cust_name":"new","u_name":"user","cnic":"421","address":"sadaddd","cell_num":"43243","email":"n@gmail.com"}}

**My Code Section is below:**

```
$user_login = $conn->prepare("SELECT u_id,cust_name,u_name,cnic,address,cell_num, email FROM users,cell_num WHERE u_name = :u_name AND password=:password AND users.u_id=cell_num.u_id_fk");
                        $user_login->execute(['u_name' => $u_name,'password'=>$password]); 


                        if($user_login->rowCount() > 0){

                            $row  = $user_login->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                            $response['user'] = $row; 
                            //echo $row;
                            //print_r($row);
```

Comment: passwords should never be stored as plain text, as we can not see the generation of $password i hoped they are hashed

Comment: As pointed out, plain text passwords are a big risk, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets means it is an array of data it's giving you rather than just one object.

Using `fetchAll()` will always return an array of rows matching the SELECT, if you know there is just one row, then you can use `fetch()` instead...

```
$row  = $user_login->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Now, i used $row  = $user_login->fetchAll(); but it is giving me same record two time.

Comment: So have you tried `fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`?